# ControlPaint.DrawBorder().....but thicker?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5, controls

I have the below code, which works, to draw a border around a control in a WinForm 3.5 app.

What I can't figure out is how to **THICKEN** the border that is being drawn.  I tried `Inflate(5,5)` on the `ClientRectangle` but that actually made the Border disappear all together versus making it thicker.

I get the impression that I actually need to be working with `e.Graphics` to accomplish this but I can't, for the life of me, figure out how.

Ideas?

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(
                    e.Graphics, datImmunizationRecieved.ClientRectangle, Color.OrangeRed, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

---

### The Answer in Action for future reference

Below is how I implemented the same Method but overloaded(*note: these are both inside a Paint_Event*)

```
var borderColor = Color.FromArgb(173, 216, 230);
var borderStyle = ButtonBorderStyle.Solid;
var borderWidth = 3;

ControlPaint.DrawBorder(
                    e.Graphics,
                    lkuNOImmunizationReason.ClientRectangle,
                    borderColor,
                    borderWidth,
                    borderStyle,
                    borderColor,
                    borderWidth,
                    borderStyle,
                    borderColor,
                    borderWidth,
                    borderStyle,
                    borderColor,
                    borderWidth,
                    borderStyle);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an overload for that method that allows you to specify the width for all of the sides -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/616fkc53.aspx

Comment: what's dumb is I had, obviously, looked at MSDN but for some reason I cannot even remember, discredited the overload as a possible solution.  Genius, pure Genius!  Thanks